# Python Mysql TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user="root", passwd="xxxx", db="xxxxx")
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM pin WHERE active=1")
     while (1):
       row = cursor.fetchone()
       st = str(row[2])
       pin = str(row[1])
       order = str(st)+str(pin)
       if row == None:
          break
       sendSerial(order)
conn.close()
```

Why st = str(row[2]) become error? 
How should retrieve rows from the database into a variable?

Thank You for your answer.

Comment: shouldn't the check `if row == None:` be before ` st = str(row[2])`??

Comment: The check should be `if row is None`, not `if row == None`.

Answer (score 11):

`st = str(row[2])` is an error because `cursor.fetchone()` returns `None` when there are no more rows.

Fix it with one of these approaches:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    do_stuff()
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

or

```
for row in cursor:
    do_stuff()
```

or

```
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is None:  # better: if not row
          break
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: `do_stuff` is nothing.  It's just a way of saying "the rest of your code goes here".